# Grouping and ordering columns in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with many columns, one of which is "movie title", I want to find the top 5 movie titles that appear in the most rows, and place them in descending order.

For example:

```
movie title

Title 1
Title 2
Title 2
Title 3
Title 3
Title 3
```

Should become:

```
movie title     count

Title 3         3
Title 2         2
Title 1         1
```

It can be in the same or a new dataframe. I may be missing a simple solution as I'm extremely new to Pandas. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Get counts of the coulmn `df['movie title'].value_counts()`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
df.groupby('movie title')['movie title'].aggregate(['count']).reset_index().sort('count', ascending=False)
```

or step by step

```
df = df.groupby('movie title')['movie title'].aggregate(['count'])
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.sort('count', ascending=False)
```

the '[ ]' inside the aggregate are important